# How to set width to 100% in WPF

Tags: wpf, width, autosize

Is there any way how to tell component in **WPF** to take 100% of available space?

Like

```
width: 100%;
```

in CSS

I've got this XAML, and I don't know how to force Grid to take 100% width.

```
<ListBox Name="lstConnections">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Background="LightPink">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=User}" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Password}" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=Host}" Margin="4"></TextBlock>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Result looks like

[alt text http://foto.darth.cz/pictures/wpf_width.jpg](http://foto.darth.cz/pictures/wpf_width.jpg)

I made it pink so it's obvious how much space does it take. I need to make the pink grid 100% width.

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @MartiniBianco I'm sorry, but this question is 8 years old. I don' even remember what was in the image, nor have I used WPF since then.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It is the container of the `Grid` that is imposing on its width. In this case, that's a `ListBoxItem`, which is left-aligned by default. You can set it to stretch as follows:

```
<ListBox>
    <!-- other XAML omitted, you just need to add the following bit -->
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: A small note - if you're trying to do this in a windows store app, you have to actually set `HorizontalContentAlignment` using the same method as above

Answer (score 70):

You could use `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` as follows:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me, with a component inside a `Grid` with 2 columns and 2 rows, was to use `Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2"`, to make it span across the columns:

```
<Grid Margin="50">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  
    <!-- InputStackPanel -->
    <local:InputStackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" InputsSource="{Binding droppedInputs}"/>

    
</Grid>
```