# WPF: Placing textbox next to radiobutton in stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radio-button

I have a stackpanel containing two radio buttons (*Option 1* and *Option 2*). If the user selects Option 2 a textbox should be active that allows the user to give some more details about Option 2.

I came up with two solutions but none of them is exactly what I want. This is how they look like:

[image: Screenshot of solution #1 and #2]

### Solution #1

The XAML-code of solution #1 is very simple and the result is pretty obvious:

```xml
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1">
        <RadioButton>Option 1</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>Option 2:</RadioButton>
        <TextBox>Some Text that details option 2</TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

What's good here is that the textbox uses the entire width. Nevertheless, that's not what I wanted since the textbox should be placed next to the Option 2.

### Solution #2

The next step was to create a grid in the RadioButton-tags. That allowed me to place the textbox at the proper position but then the width doesn't scale up to 100 % anymore.

The code looks like this:

```xml
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1">
        <RadioButton>Option 1</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" >Option 2:</TextBlock>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">Some Text that details option 2</TextBox>
            </Grid>
        </RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
```

Besides the point that this looks to me like a quite over-engineered solution, the question is here: *How to set the width of grid within a radio button entry to 100%?*

A similar question was asked here ([How to set width to 100% in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787436/how-to-set-width-to-100-in-wpf)) but using the `ItemContainerStyle` property does not work for radiobuttons.

In my eyes, there must be a much easier (or at least a working) solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="1">
    <RadioButton>Option 1</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel  LastChildFill="True">
            <TextBlock >Option 2:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"  
                     Margin="10,0,0,0">Some Text that </TextBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Or if you want to keep the Grid:

```
 <StackPanel Grid.Row="8"
            Grid.Column="1">
    <RadioButton>Option 1</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock >Option 2:</TextBlock>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1"  
                     Margin="10,0,0,0">Some Text that </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Which solution would you prefer? To me the grid-solution is a bit more intuitive. What do you think?

Comment: I like the DockPanel one more.

Answer (score 1):

You can design anyway you want. Just apply same `GroupName` to all RadioButtons

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Option1" GroupName="Question" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Content="Option2" GroupName="Question" />
        <TextBox Text="Other controls"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can try out -

1. Set the HorizontalAlignment of the 2nd RadioButton to "Stretch";
2. Try setting it on the Grid instead;
3. Having a ColumnDefinition set to "Auto" and another one at "130*" doesn't really make any sense. Have the first one at Auto (will size itself to content) and the second one at "*" (use all the available space)

The * sizing is relative. If you had 1* and 2*, 2* would always be twice as big as 1*. Same thing with 0.5* and 1*, the first one will always be half the size of 1*.

Did you try setting both ColumnDefinitions to Auto?

Else, something you can use to troubleshoot this sort of thing is to apply a border around your elements (each element gets a different border color). It helps finding which control is the culprit.

Comment: HorizontalAlignment is not enough, He should set HorizontalContentAlignment